# late initialization error flutter: Field _origin has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is the error message drawn from the debug console:
The following LateError was thrown building MapScreen(dirty, state: _MapScreenState#53750):
LateInitializationError: Field '_origin' has not been initialized.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
MapScreen

Here is the code snippet drawn from the MapScreen dart file:

```
class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  static const _initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(-1.286389, 36.817223),
    zoom: 11.5,
  );
  late GoogleMapController _googleMapController;
  late Marker _origin;
  late Marker _destination;
  late Directions _info;
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _googleMapController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        title: const Text('Google Maps'),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => _googleMapController.animateCamera(
              CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                CameraPosition(
                  target: _origin.position,
                  zoom: 14.5,
                  tilt: 50.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.green,
              textStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            ),
            child: const Text('ORIGIN'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => _googleMapController.animateCamera(
              CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                CameraPosition(
                    target: _destination.position, zoom: 14.5, tilt: 50.0),
              ),
            ),
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.blue,
              textStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            ),
            child: const Text('DEST'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          GoogleMap(
            myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
            zoomControlsEnabled: false,
            initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
            onMapCreated: (controller) => _googleMapController = controller,
            markers: {
              if (_origin != null) _origin,
              if (_destination != null) _destination,
            },
            polylines: {
              if (_info != null)
              Polyline(polylineId: const PolylineId('overview_polyline'),
              color: Colors.red,
              width: 5,
              points: _info.polylinePoints
              .map((e) => LatLng(e.latitude, e.longitude))
              .toList(),
              ),
            },
            onLongPress: _addMarker,
          ),
          if (_info != null)
            Positioned(
            top: 20.0,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 6.0, 
              horizontal: 12.0
              ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.yellowAccent,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black26,
                  offset: Offset (0, 2),
                  blurRadius: 6.0,
                ),
              ]
            ),
            child: Text(
              '${_info.totalDistance}, ${_info.totalDuration}',
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
            ),
            ),
            
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        onPressed: () => _googleMapController.animateCamera(
          _info != null
          ? CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(_info.bounds, 100.0)
          : CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_initialCameraPosition),
        ),
        child: const Icon(Icons.center_focus_strong),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _addMarker(LatLng pos) async {
    if (_origin == null || (_origin != null && _destination != null)) {
      setState(() {
        _origin = Marker(
          markerId: const MarkerId('origin'),
          infoWindow: const InfoWindow(title: 'origin'),
          icon:
              BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen),
          position: pos,
        );
        //Reset Destination
        var __destination = null;
        _destination = __destination;
        var __info = null;
        _info = __info;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _origin = Marker(
          markerId: const MarkerId('destination'),
          infoWindow: const InfoWindow(title: 'destination'),
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue),
          position: pos,
        );
      });
      final directions = await DirectionsRepository()
      .getDirections(origin: _origin.position, destination: pos);
      setState(() => _info = directions!);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are using `_origin` like it is a nullable variable instead of a late variable. You should remove `late` and change the type to `Marker?`.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of `late` for `_origin` is problematic since `late` should be used to promise the Dart compiler that the variable are going to be provided a value before the first time you are trying to read the variable.

There are therefore not a concept of checking if a `late` variable have been set or not since you have promised that you are going to provide a value before the first read.

The reason we have `late` is for certain situations where we cannot ensure a non-nullable variable are initialized with a value but we know, as a developer, that the variable is always going to be a non-nullable value in the context of the program since you know that the variable are being provided a value before the first access.

In your situation, you do check if the variable have been provided a value or not. This pattern is a clear sign that your `_origin` variable should not have been defined as `late` but instead a nullable type (so `Marker?` instead of `Marker`).

By using a nullable type, the variable is allowed to contain the value `null` and you can check for this and define the variable if needed later. The usage of a nullable type will also force you into checking if the variable is null or not in case you are going to use the value. Which is fine since that ensures your program are actually taking care of situations where the variable might be `null`.